# How to update defaultLabel dynamically in primeNg multiselect

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, primeng-datatable, primeng-dropdowns

In primeNg multiselect I'm unselecting the items from ts file, I can able to unselect but this will not gets updated in the input field.

**someComponent.html**

```
<p-multiSelect [options]="cities1" maxSelectedLabels=0 selectedItemsLabel="{0} 
items selected" [(ngModel)]="selectedCities1"></p-multiSelect>
<div *ngFor="let city in selectedCities1 let i=index">
  <button (click)="delete(i)">{{city}}</button>
</div>
```

**someComponent.ts**

```
delete(i){
//using splice method to remove item from selectedCities1 array
}
```

Question is when I select and unselect from dropdown I am able to see the output like "1 item selected" "2 item selected" etc and vice-versa.

[image]

But when I do it from delete function I can unselect dropdown but unable to update the defaultLabel with "1 item selected" "2 item selected" etc and vice-versa.

[image]

Tried very much and searched in all primeng Q&A but unable to find answer.

Answer (score 4):

It's weird since the writeValue should be called if you use the splice.

you can try the slice after the item removed. This will create a new array:

```
this.selectedCities1 = this.selectedCities1.slice();
```

But here is a hack:

```
<p-multiSelect #sel [options]="cities1" maxSelectedLabels=0 selectedItemsLabel="{0} 
items selected" [(ngModel)]="selectedCities1"></p-multiSelect>
<div *ngFor="let city in selectedCities1 let i=index">
  <button (click)="delete(i);sel.updateLabel()">{{city}}</button>
</div>
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: Awsome tano.. But they not mentioned anywhere about this updateLabel() in the documentation. Thanks anyways.

Comment: After upgrading to latest version this no longer seems to work. Is there an alternative in doing this in version 15.1.1 of prime?